# How to Stop a Thread when Using Handler in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I'm going to make several images that are to be changing by Handler when they are clicked.
But now there are only two images for a test. 
I want to change the images in two processes of clicking on them.
The first process should be stopped when the imaged was clicked again.
In my code, however, the first process doesn't stop. 
I can see that both processes are simultaneously acting along.

How can I stop the first thread, and how can I manage one by one when there are many threads are going on?

Here is my code below.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    ImageView img2;
    ImageView img3;

    Button btn;
    Handler myHandler;
    Runnable myRun;
    int flag_number;

 int img1_phase = 0;

    //click method for image 1
    public void img1_click (View view) {
        flag_number = 1;
        click_change_Image(img, img1_phase);

        myRun = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                time_change_image(img, img1_phase);
            }
        };
        new Thread(myRun).start();

        }
    }



//Click method for 2nd process
    public void click_change_Image(final ImageView imageView, int phase) {

        if (phase == 4 || phase == 5) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.second_1);
            myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //this code doesn't work
            Thread.interrupted();// not work either
            phase = 7;
        }

        image_checker(phase);

        return;
    }



  //Change Image Process by Thread after Clicked
public void time_change_image(final ImageView imageView, int phase) {
        if (phase == 0) {
            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.new_one_1, 300);
            phase = 1;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.new_one_2, 300);
            phase = 2;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.first_1, 300);
            phase = 3;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.first_2, 3000);
            phase = 4;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.first_3, 3000);
            phase = 5;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.first_4, 3000);
            phase = 6;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.empty, 3000);
            phase = 0;
            image_checker(phase);

        }else if(phase == 7) {

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.second_2, 3000);
            phase = 8;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.second_3, 3000);
            phase = 9;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.second_4, 3000);
            phase = 10;
            image_checker(phase);

            change_Image(imageView, R.drawable.empty, 3000);
            phase = 0;
            image_checker(phase);

        }

        flag_number = 0;

    }



 //Change Image Resource method
    public void change_Image(final ImageView iv, final int image, int wait_time) {
            sleep_Thread(wait_time);
            myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    iv.setImageResource(image);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a flag to manage your thread. For instance:

```
boolean isRun = true (global variable)
   myRun = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(isRun) {
               time_change_image(img, img1_phase);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Handler to avoid delay in main thread.

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

to start a thread:

```
 mHandler.post(Runnable);
```

or

```
mHandler.postDelayed(Runnable, some delayTime)
```

to stop

```
 mHandler.removeCallback(Runnable);
```